# Error función recursiva

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursión

Tengo la siguiente función que se debe estar ejecutándose constantemente en un intervalo de X minutos para traer datos desde dispositivo externo y guardarlos en mi base de datos, para esto consulto los minutos para el siguiente intervalo, luego obtengo los datos desde el dispositivo, los inserto en la base de datos y luego con método sleep() dejo esperando el tiempo correspondiente para el siguiente intervalo y la función vuelve a llamarse  a si misma, pero luego de un par de intervalos esta se detiene.

```php
public function index()
        {
            $conf = $this->ws->obtener(27);
            $dispositivos = $this->ws->listar(26);

            foreach ($dispositivos as $key => $d) {
                $data = $this->egauge->getDataEgauge($d->codigo, $d->ruta, $conf);
                $this->ws->insertar(28, $data);
            }

            $seg = $conf->intervalo * 60;
            sleep($seg);

            unset($conf);
            unset($dispositivos);
            unset($data);
            unset($seg);

            $this->index();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿ Es necesario que sea recursiva ?. Porque si lo pasas a iterativo sería más fácil y no sobrecargarías el sistema( pues cada nueva retrollamada, la pila del interprete se va llenando ).

Te propongo una solución alternativa:

```php
public function index()
{
   while( true ) {
        $conf = $this->ws->obtener(27);
        $dispositivos = $this->ws->listar(26);

        foreach ($dispositivos as $key => $d) {
            $data = $this->egauge->getDataEgauge($d->codigo, $d->ruta, $conf);
            $this->ws->insertar(28, $data);
        }

        $seg = $conf->intervalo * 60;
        sleep($seg);
    }
}
```

Este código evitará que se llene la pila y se pare el script.

También puede pasar que tu script termine porque tiene un [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). En ese caso, te recomiendo ejecutar el script desde terminal o como tarea CRON.

¡ Suerte !